# difference between sabertooth motor controller and rc esc?

Tags: motor, esc

i am building a rc/robot mower.

most of the youtube videos show the sabertooth motor controllers being used to connect the rc receiver to the dc motors.

But here in Australia, the sabertooth i need cost about 200 dollars. RC esc sell for about 10 dollars.

What is the difference between the esc and the sabertooth and can i use an esc instead?

the specs i have on the motor and battery are 12v 10amp normal, 35amp stall. and my rc is a flysky

Comment: Where did you end up getting the RC ESCs from?

Comment: from ebay https://www.ebay.com.au/sch/sis.html?_itemId=222417846902&_nkw=320A+Brushed+Speed+Controller+ESC+f+1+8+1+10+RC+Electric+Car+Truck+Buggy+Boat+CX&_trksid=p2047675.m4099.l9146

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have ended up using 2 RC ESCs they can easily handle the 35 amps and 12v.  the flysky remote also allows mixing so that the 2 motors/escs can handle skid steering on one stick of the remote.  So much cheaper

Answer (score 0):

The Sabertooth Motor Controller is for driving DC motors, where most RC escs are for driving AC (brushless) motors. If the motor you have is a DC motor there are plenty of other motor drivers out there that can supply the 35A stall current, that you might find cheaper in your country.

I have listed some below

- [Victor](https://www.vexrobotics.com/vexpro/motors-electronics/217-9090.html)
- [RoboClaw 2x45A](https://www.pololu.com/product/2397)
- [Cytron 40A](http://www.robotshop.com/en/cytron-single-10--45v-40a-brushed-dc-motor-controller.html)

Comment: thanks for the list Mark. i will check them out.  although victor and cytron look to be single, so have to double up on them.   this esc is for brushed motors and is $10.  http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/320A-Brushed-Speed-Controller-ESC-f-1-8-1-10-RC-Electric-Car-Truck-Buggy-Boat-CX/222417846902